# Reshaping a Julia-stored array in Python

Tags: python, julia

I'm struggling with this issue since a while now, so I decided to ask you for some help. So, for short, my problem is the following...

All of my codes are in Julia, and the data processed by them has been stored as Julia does(I guess in column-major oder), but now I need to run some code in python that reads some of these data and reshape it. But, as the data is stored and read differently in both lenguajes, reshaping is not behaving as I would excpect (not that it is wrong, just not what I wanted)
As an example...
In Julia, when I reshape an 1D-array into a (2,3,4)-array dimention, I get:

```
julia> a=collect(1:24);
julia> r=reshape(a,2,3,4)
2×3×4 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
1  3  5
2  4  6

[:, :, 2] =
7   9  11
8  10  12

[:, :, 3] =
13  15  17
14  16  18

[:, :, 4] =
19  21  23
20  22  24
```

While in python I get,

```
b=np.arange(1,25);
r=b.reshape(4,2,3)
```

gives

```
In [200]: r
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6]],

   [[ 7,  8,  9],
    [10, 11, 12]],

   [[13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18]],

   [[19, 20, 21],
    [22, 23, 24]]])
```

Is there any way to achieve in Python the same result of that obtained in the Julia example?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
>>> np.transpose(b.reshape(4,3,2), (2,1,0))
array([[[ 1,  7, 13, 19],
        [ 3,  9, 15, 21],
        [ 5, 11, 17, 23]],

       [[ 2,  8, 14, 20],
        [ 4, 10, 16, 22],
        [ 6, 12, 18, 24]]])
```

EDIT:

As explained in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html the second argument of `np.transpose` permutes axes of an array according to the values given as a second argument. Actually in this case you could just write `np.transpose(b.reshape(4,3,2))` as by default `np.transpose` reverses the dimensions which is needed here.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Now, i failed to see how is your result similar of that I posted(given the same array b). Your result "r" using Python Is not the same as mine using Julia... am I misstaken?

Comment: It is the same result. It's just displayed in different ways in Julia and Python. For every `i,j,k` the value `r[i,j,k]` is the same in Julia and Python.

Comment: Exactly like @crstnbr noted - it is only the difference in display and the fact that in Python arrays are 0-indexed and in Julia 1-indexed, so you have to shift all indices by 1.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński thanks for the answer. I now see that is indeed the same result. But, would you care to explain what is the meaning of the second argument pased inside "np.transpose" function?. I guess it has something to do with an  axes permutation, but it is not clear to me hw it actuallt works...